# Postman python code snippet does not work in my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, postman

I have a POST request that I made and it is working fine on PostMan; I received a code 200, However, when I intergrate the code snippet I took from PostMan into my code in visual studio code, I receive a Bad Request (400).

This is the body of my PostMan request.
[image]

The code snippet I received from PostMan is shown below

```
import requests

url = "https://myurl/test"

payload = {}
files = [
      ('file', open('C:/test.json','rb'))
      ]
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
   'Authorization': 'Bearer xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx'
 }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: `payload` is empty.  Is it supposed to be?

Comment: I think so because I am uploading a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I Just added this to my code

```
files = [
        ('file', open('C:/test.json','rb'),'application/json'))
        ]
```