# How to retrieve file object in python sent via Postman without any url

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, postman

I am sending a file as an object via postman POST or PUT API like below:

[image: Postman request example]

How can I in Python -

1. get this file object
2. read and save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question which i finally implemented without url -

```
@app.route('/uploadFIle', methods=['PUT'])
def uploadFile():
    chunk_size = 4096
    with open("/Users/xyz/Documents/filename", 'wb') as f:
        while True:
            chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                break
            f.write(chunk)
    return jsonify({"success":"File transfer initiated"})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a working request in Postman, you could copy autogenerated `Code Snippet` in `Python - Requests` format:

[image: Code snippet example]

[image: Code snippet example 2]

It might look like this:

```
import requests

url = "localhost:8080"

payload="<file contents here>"
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: This also might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62944674/11922633

Comment: this seems viable for a development environment, I don't think it's a feasible solution for the production environment. 
is there any way we can leverage flask by using request.stream.read() ?
How do I save this data ?